# Bash - How do I define functions in the terminal over multiple lines?

Tags: bash

how do I define functions in the terminal over multiple lines?

```
# this doesn't work
function my_func { \
  echo "number 5" \
}
```

Very basic. Still pesky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `\` to continue lines here.  Try:

```bsh
function my_func {
  echo "number 5" 
}
```

The `function` keyword isn't required, you can use `funcname () {...}` instead:

```bsh
my_func() {
  echo "number 5" 
}
```

BTW, the reason it's not working is that the backslashes make the function definition all one line, and one-line function definitions need to end with a `;` in bash.

e.g. this fails:

```
my_func () { echo "number 5" }
```

this works:

```
my_func () { echo "number 5" ; }
```

as does this:

```bsh
function my_func { \
  echo "number 5" \
  ; \
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!